# Userform called Userform TextBox Control behavior

Tags: vba, excel, userform

So I have an excel workbook that opens userform1 on the workbook open event.
Once certain conditions are met on userform1 it calls a procedure that loads and shows userform2.  Userform2 has a label, a textbox and a button.  This issue I have is that the events for the textbox on userform2 don't all fire correctly.  The KeyUp & KeyDown events fire as expected, but the Change and AfterUpdate event never get called.
I've been able to replicate the behavior in another workbook that is greatly simplified.  If you key or paste a text string longer than 7 characters in the textbox on userform1 it loads userform2.  The desired behavior is to key in a 3 digit numeric value in the textbox on userform2 and call a sub from userform1.  This never happens.  Has anyone else seen this behavior before?  How did you work around it?

USERFORM1: (excuse the Ascii art, evidently I don't have enough reputation to post images) :/

---

```
Label1:             [ Textbox1 ]
Label2:



              [ CommandButton1 ]
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
If Me.TextBox1.TextLength >= 7 Then
    Load UserForm2
    UserForm2.Label1.Caption = "Value for " & Me.TextBox1.Text & "?"
    UserForm2.Show
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Form2(data As Variant)
On Error GoTo eh
Me.Label2.Caption = Me.Label2.Caption & vbCrLf & Me.TextBox1.Text & vbTab & CStr(CLng(data))
eh:
If Err.Number = 13 Then
    MsgBox "Please input a #"
    UserForm2.TextBox1.SetFocus
ElseIf Err.Number = 0 Then
    Unload UserForm2
End If
End Sub
```

USERFORM2:

---

```
label1:    [ Textbox1 ]
     [ CommandButton1 ]
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call UserForm1.Form2(Me.TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
'This event never fires
If Me.TextBox1.TextLength >= 3 Then
    Call UserForm1.Form2(Me.TextBox1.Text)
Else
    Debug.Print "here"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
'This event fires
Debug.Print KeyCode
End Sub
```

Comment: Chad, I have replicated your problem and have a work around below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this happens as you can run userform2 by itself and it works. However to get around this to start with it might be best to put the code in keyUp event. That should work

EDIT

I have found a slight work around. It is not perfect as I cannot find out why it is not firing. However the up and down key press works fine. I have added this code and now the event should fire. But it is a semi-manual event.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)    
    Call TextBox2_Change
End Sub
```

So when a key is pressed down. It will check for any changes.

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing with this as well.  The problem I have is that I am using a peripheral device for input.  When it scans the external data and pastes it into the textbox, The only event that fires is the BeforeDropOrPaste event, but it fires before the value has been updated, so I can't check the value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making use of the KeyUp and BeforeDropOrPaste.

Sam, thanks for the inspiration.  I was trying to replicate the code of the Change event into the actual procedure.  I ended up calling the event directly from the KeyUp procedure and using `Application.OnTime "UserForm2.TextBox1_Change"` in the BeforeDropOrPaste event to get around the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is showing the 2nd userform modally. In this situation, the TextBox1_Change() procedure in the 1st form is not allowed to complete while the 2nd userform is displayed. This interferes with the event messaging.

To resolve the issue, simply show the 2nd userform modelessly:

```
    UserForm2.Show vbModeless
```

Please do not resort to the suggested hack.

Comment: I tried that as well, but so long as the first userform is shown modal (which it has to be) the second userform has to be as well.  It will not allow me to open a modeless userform from a modal userform.

Answer (score 0):

Excel Hero is correct, the only point is to load a modeless userform next to a modal userform you have to `.hide` the modal userform so it will not interfere with the modeless userform.

see code below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
If Me.TextBox1.TextLength >= 7 Then
    Me.hide
    Load UserForm2 vbModeless
    UserForm2.Label1.Caption = "Value for " & Me.TextBox1.Text & "?"
    UserForm2.Show
End If
End Sub
```

you can load UserForm2 as vbModeless or make the userform by default modeless.